# Distillery not replacing environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery

In my umbrella project using distillery for releases, I have a `db` app `config` with the following:

```
config :main, Main.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "${DB_USERNAME}",
  password: "${DB_PASSWORD}",
  database: "${DB_NAME}",
  hostname: "${DB_HOST}",
  pool_size: 10
```

As I have set `REPLACE_OS_VARS=true` in my build, the environment vars are read correctly configures the database.

I have a similar set up in an email `app` which has the following config:

```
config :email, from_email: "${FROM_EMAIL}"
```

I am then looking to access this from inside my `email` app, like so:

```
@from_email Application.get_env(:email, :from_email)
```

But the value of `@from_email` is `"${FROM_EMAIL}"` not the environment variable I set for `FROM_EMAIL`.

I am not too familiar with how distillery works and am unsure how passing in these environment variables in these similar ways is causing it to be read differently.

Insight as to why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**:

We are able to pass the `$FROM_EMAIL` environment variable in when distillery compiles, but we would like to pass this in at run time.
We are able to do this in the `db` app, but not in the `email` app for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but why would that come to mind? I have double checked and it and the `FROM_EMAIL` var is set, would it be an issue with not passing it in to app correctly

Comment: Instead of storing in a module attribute, try calling `Application.get_env(:email, :from_email)` at runtime.

Comment: That's the answer, thanks a bunch @Dogbert. Post an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code directly inside the module definition (i.e. outside `def`) is evaluated at compile time. You'll need to call `Application.get_env` at runtime to get the correct value:

Add:

```
def from_email, do: Application.get_env(:email, :from_email)
```

to the module and then change all `@from_email` in the module to `from_email()`.